# How to access all data from pivot table laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am a beginner in Laravel and am stuck with sending the data from pivot table to view. I have two models one is "Supplier" and another is "Product" which I have created as follows:

**Supplier.php**

```
class Supplier extends Model
{
    protected $keyType = 'string';

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
                'App\Product',
                'inward_stock',
                'supplier_id',
                'product_id'
            )->withPivot(
                'product_dimension',
                'quantity',
                'expiry_date',
                'type',
                'QR_code',
                'sales_price',
                'arrival_date',
                'occassion',
                'discount_percentage',
                'payment_date',
                'cost',
                'paid_status',
                'sku'
            )->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Product.php**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $keyType = 'string';
    protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';

    public $incrementing = false;

    public function suppliers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Supplier');
    }
}
```

Now I want to access all the data from the pivot table named as "inward_stock" from my controller and want to send it to the view named "inward-stock-list", I have created "inwardstockController" for that purpose and want to know how to send it to the view using that controller.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many   check the section on retrieving pivot data

Comment: yes, I have checked that but I want to send all data not by just finding each entry but in an efficient way.

Comment: You need better model of your business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most effective way is to create model for pivot table:

```
class InwardStock extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'inward_stock';

    public function supplier()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Supplier', 'supplier_id', 'supplier_id');
    }

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product', 'product_id', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

inwardstockController:

```
$inwardStocks = InwartStock::with(['product', 'supplier'])->get();
```

View:

```
@foreach($inwardStocks as $inwardStock)
    {{ $inwardStock->supplier->id }}
    {{ $inwardStock->product->id }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but when laravel defines the pivot by itself why should I worry about creating separate model?

Comment: This solution based on your task. I agree with comment about logic. Imho, pivot table should not have a lot of additional data. Looks like this table needs independent model.

Comment: I wanted to say that Product has many InwardStock, Supplier has Many InwarStock, and there is no promlem to access suppliers from Product and products from Supplier trough InwardStock